# Simple thread program to understand synchronized, wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm looking at other examples here and in other sites and I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to do a program that one thread sets the value of an object to the values 1 to 10, but I want to wait for it to change the value until other thread reads it, so I can print them and have a list from 1 to 10.

My readThread run method just loops from 1 to 10 calling the following method:

```
private synchronized int receive() {
    try {
        wait();
        int value = this.mainThread.getValor();
        notify();
        return value;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;  
}
```

My writeThread run method just loops from 1 to 10 calling the following method:

```
private synchronized void send(int n) {
    try {
        this.mainThread.setValor(n);
        notify();
        wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The main method is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainThread mt = new MainThread();
    ReadThread rt = new ReadThread(mt);
    WriteThread wt = new WriteThread(mt);
    
    wt.start();
    rt.start();

}
```

The class MainThead has the property "valor" defined with its getter and setter

Thank you for your help

Comment: As Tom mentioned below there are quite a few potential problems.  As the code stands it's a decent example of a Producer Consumer problem.  The main thing I see missing is there's no way to tell when a value has been produced (written) and when it has been consumed (read).  If you add that I think you will get it working.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of obvious problems.

It looks as if you are synchronising on the same lock (there isn't enough code to be 100% sure). Generally you should create an object specifically to use as a lock.

`send` may be executed before `receive`. In that case the first `notify` will do nothing, and both threads will stall in `wait`.

In theory, there is no guarantee that `wait` will not wakeup spontaneously. For this and other reasons, you really want the `wait` inside a `while` loop.